# Migrating from GA Universal to GA4 for Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, migration

We have a website and an app. We were tracking both with google analytics universal. Firebase created its own View in Google Analytics we were tracking both web and app over different views. Now Google isnt supporting universal anymore. We have switched the Web to GA4 but I cant link the Firebase app statistics to it. I also dont want to lose old Firebase data. What steps shall we follow?

Do I need to create a new Firebase project and link to our new GA4? Or do I need to unlink old Firebase project and then is there a possibility to link to new GA4? Will there be any data lost? Before making these clicks/links, Im a bit hesistant. Would be glad for any tips!

Answer (score 0):

You just [link your GA4 to FB](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9289234?hl=en) by adding new data streams in your property to effectively make it an App+Web property.